# How to pass value from activity to ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

How to pass value from Activity to View Model? I try to find anything on web but I failed. What I want is this: I have two recyclerviews in one activity. If user click on item A in recyclerview 1 I want to send ID of this item to View Model and return something by this ID. There is an error with *dokladId* parameter in *testToShow* variable.

What is the easy way to handle it?

This is my ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SkladViewModel @Inject constructor(
    repository: SybaseRepository
): ViewModel(){
    val skladyPolozky = repository.getAllSkladFromPolozka().asLiveData()
    val dokladyPolozky = repository.getAllHlavickyToDoklad().asLiveData()
    val testToShow = repository.getSelectedDokladyBySklad(dokladId).asLiveData()
}
```

This is the activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DokladActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SkladAdapter.OnItemClickListener, DokladAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private val skladViewModel: SkladViewModel by viewModels()

    //private val dokladViewModel: DokladViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityDokladBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_doklad)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.btVybratDoklad.setOnClickListener{
            openActivity(binding.root)
        }
        val skladAdapter = SkladAdapter (this)
        val dokladAdapter = DokladAdapter(this)
        binding.apply {
            recyclerViewSklady.apply {
                adapter = skladAdapter
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@DokladActivity)
            }
            skladViewModel.skladyPolozky.observe(this@DokladActivity) {
                skladAdapter.submitList(it)
                Log.d("Doklad", skladAdapter.currentList.toString())
            }
            recyclerViewDoklady.apply {
                adapter = dokladAdapter
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@DokladActivity)
            }
            skladViewModel.dokladyPolozky.observe(this@DokladActivity){
                dokladAdapter.submitList(it)
                Log.d("Doklad", dokladAdapter.currentList.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    fun openActivity(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this,PolozkaActivity::class.java )
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onItemClick(polozkaSklad: SkladTuple) {
        val action = polozkaSklad.reg
    }

    override fun onItemClick(polozkaHlavicka: DokladTuple) {
        val intent = Intent(this, PolozkaActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("doklad", polozkaHlavicka.doklad)
        //intent.putExtra("polozkaHlavicka", polozkaHlavicka as Serializable)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Repository with some function:

```
fun getSelectedDokladyBySklad(sklad: Int) : Flow<List<SkladDokladTuple>>{
        return sybaseDao.getAllDokladFromPolozkaBySklad(sklad)
    }
```

and DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT distinct doklad FROM cis06zebrap where sklad=:skladId")
    fun getAllDokladFromPolozkaBySklad(skladId:Int?=null): Flow<List<SkladDokladTuple>>
```

Comment: You have `ViewModel` instance in Activity . That's all you need . Just call a method .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@HiltViewModel
class SkladViewModel @Inject constructor(
    repository: SybaseRepository
): ViewModel(){
    val skladyPolozky = repository.getAllSkladFromPolozka().asLiveData()
    val dokladyPolozky = repository.getAllHlavickyToDoklad().asLiveData()
    val testToShow = repository.getSelectedDokladyBySklad(dokladId).asLiveData()


   fun someNameYouFindUseful(id: String) {
      // do something with the id
      ...
      // notify the UI
      someLiveDataYouShoudlBeObservingFromTheUI.value = SomeSealedClassWrappingTheStates.SomeStateYouFindDescriptive

   } 
}
```

Then in your Activity/Fragment you'd do:

```
  viewModel.someNameYouFindUseful("the Id")
```

Since you will likely have a viewModel reference there.

To complete the missing pieces, please take a look at [the Google official documentation about ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) including how to expose a "state" and react to it.